# Python - Set class property to depend on values of other properties in the same class

Tags: python, class, function, methods, properties

Sorry if this already exists somewhere in the question archives, but I'm not sure how to ask it and searching didn't lead to any great revelations.

In Python (2.6.x) I have created a class

```
class timetuple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weekday = 6
        self.month   = 1
        self.day     = 1
        self.year    = 2011
        self.hour    = 0
        self.min     = 0
        self.sec     = 0
    def jd(self):
        self.jd = julian_date(self)

def julian_date(obj):
    (Code to calculate a Julian Date snipped)

start = timetuple()
start.day   = 23
start.month = 2
start.year  = 2011
start.hour  = 13
start.min   = 30
start.sec   = 0

print start.__dict__
start.jd()
print start.__dict__
print start.jd
```

Which returns

```
{'hour': 13, 'min': 30, 'month': 2, 'sec': 0, 'weekday': 6, 'year': 2011, 'date': 23, 'day': 1}
{'hour': 13, 'min': 30, 'month': 14, 'jd': 2455594.0625, 'sec': 0, 'weekday': 6, 'year': 2010, 'date': 23, 'day': 1}
2455594.0625
```

So the .jd property (or do I call this a function or a method? I'm unsure of the lingo here honestly) doesn't exist before the start.jd() call.  Is there a way I can somehow rewrite this to make it always exist based on the current values in the timetuple class, or have it update itself when the .jd property is called?

I know I can do it the long way by just making a .jd property in the **init**(self) section and then do something like

```
start = timetuple()
start.jd = julian_date(start)
```

but I'd like to know how to set up my classes better honestly :)

Comment: ".jd" in your case is defined as  metho, and inside that method, redefiens itself as a property. This code probably will  not work as expected since you are using .jd as both a name for a methoda and an instance property

Comment: Amber's answer is a good one; but what you have here is very strange. Why didn't you just put `self.jd = julian_date(self)` in `__init__()`?

Comment: @senderle: Putting it in the `__init__` section it only updates once when an instance of the class is created and does not update the .jd property when the other properties are changed afterwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to actually define a property, as opposed to a variable:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1

    @property
    def a_plus_b(self):
        return self.a + self.b

foo = A()
print foo.a_plus_b # prints "2"
foo.a = 3
print foo.a_plus_b # prints "4"
foo.b = 4
print foo.a_plus_b # prints "7"
```

Comment: Ahh, there we go!  That works for me, thanks for the great clear example!